# SAS token generation for calling azure rest API in JAVA

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, azure-iot-hub, sas-token

I am trying to generate an SAS token using the code snippet given in the azure IoT Hub documentation, to call a GET devices API in IoT Hub(https://iot-hub-name.azure-devices.net/devices?api-version=2020-03-13).
The code is

```
private static String GetSASToken(String resourceUri, String keyName, String key)
    {
        long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L;
        int week = 60*60*24*7;
        String expiry = Long.toString(epoch + week);

        String sasToken = null;
        try {
            String stringToSign = URLEncoder.encode(resourceUri, "UTF-8") + "\n" + expiry;
            String signature = getHMAC256(key, stringToSign);
            sasToken = "SharedAccessSignature sr=" + resourceUri +"&sig=" +
                    URLEncoder.encode(signature, "UTF-8") + "&se=" + expiry + "&skn=" + keyName;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sasToken;
    }


  public static String getHMAC256(String key, String input) {
      Mac sha256_HMAC = null;
      String hash = null;
      try {
          sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
          SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
          sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
          Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();

          hash = new String(encoder.encode(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(input.getBytes("UTF-8"))));

      } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return hash;
  }
```

Then i have called the generate SAS token method as,

```
String sasToken= GetSASToken("https://<iot-hub-name>.azure-devices.net", "shared access policy name", "primary key of the shared access policy");
```

But the SAS token generated is giving a 401 Unauthorised, which means the token generated isnt proper.
Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Hi Rakesh, did the answer help you at all? If it solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise please let me know if I can help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the code in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token#java)? While IoT Hub does expose an EventHub, this is not the correct SAS Token to call the API.

You can use the [Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java) to generate your token. If you insist on writing the code yourself, [this class](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/blob/master/service/iot-service-client/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/sdk/iot/service/auth/IotHubServiceSasToken.java) holds the code you're looking for. The class will retrieve the values you need from a service connection string, but you can easily leave that out. A connection string just has the values you also have:

```
HostName=<hub-name>;SharedAccessKeyName=<policy-name>;SharedAccessKey=<access-key>
```

The class I linked extracts the values from that string and uses them in the `private String buildToken()` method, that method contains the code you're re-implementing.

Please also note, in your question you were using `https://<iot-hub-name>.azure-devices.net` as the resource name, for this token (just like in the connection string), you can leave out the `https://`

To complete my answer, you can change the constructor to this and you will have your token:

```
public IotHubServiceSasToken(String hubName, String keyValue, String keyName)
    {            
        this.resourceUri = hubName;
        this.keyValue = keyValue;
        this.keyName = keyName;
        this.expiryTime = buildExpiresOn();
        this.token =  buildToken();
    }
```

Comment: The use case i am working on, cannot employ the use of an SDK. Also the class which you have provided has "IotHubConnectionString", which is a class from the SDK. So i dont think that the solution has been met yet sadly.

Comment: The connection string is only used to transport the same values you use in your example, I have updated my answer to make it more clear. Sorry if it wasn't before!